# Python iterating over excel files in a folder

Tags: python, excel

I am interested in getting this script to open an excel file, and save it again as a .csv or .txt file.  I'm pretty sure the problem with this is the iteration - I haven't coded it correctly to iterate properly over the contents of the folder.  I am new to Python, and I managed to get this code to sucessfully print a copy of the contents of the items in the folder by the commented out part.  Can someone please advise what needs to be fixed?

My error is: raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import csv
import glob
import os
import openpyxl

cwd= os.getcwd()
print (cwd)

FileList = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
#print(FileList)

for i in FileList:
    rb = open_workbook(i)
    wb = copy(rb)
    wb.save('new_document.csv')
```

Comment: one quick way is to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), ``import pandas as pd; pd.read_excel("<file_path>").to_csv("<ouptut_path>", index=False)``

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work, in part because I want to iterate over the contents of a folder.

Comment: It looks like it should work, can you `print(list(FileList))`

Comment: This is when I tried your code above: 

```

  File "C:\Users\gittel\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Country,'
```

Comment: For print(list(FileList)):

```
runfile('F:/Design/Projects/Website/OPtimized Photos/Agent Area/ip Info reports/June 22 reports/trying again.py', wdir='F:/Design/Projects/Website/OPtimized Photos/Agent Area/ip Info reports/June 22 reports')
['Algeria.xlsx', 'Angola.xlsx', 'Argentina.xlsx', 'Australia.xlsx', 'Bosnia Herzegovina.xlsx', 'Brazil.xlsx', 'Chile.xlsx', 'China.xlsx', 'Colombia.xlsx', 'Ecuador.xlsx', 'Egypt.xlsx', 'EU.xlsx', 'Hong Kong.xlsx', 'India.xlsx', 'Italy.xlsx', 'Kenya.xlsx', 'Lebanon.xlsx', 'Mexico.xlsx', 'Morocco.xlsx'']
```

Comment: In your posted code, there's an uppercase 'F' in 'For'. There shouldn't be.

Comment: @TurePålsson thank you.  I've fixed that, but it still gives me an error:

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Country,'

Comment: Please update your question; right now it still states that you get a syntax error. Then have a close look at your file — my guess would be that it's a CSV file, not an Excel file, but I may be wrong about that.

Comment: @TurePålsson I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

file_list = glob.glob('*.xlsx')

for file in file_list:
    filename = os.path.split(file, )[1]
    pd.read_excel(file).to_csv(filename.replace('xlsx', 'csv'), index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your error is related to the excel files, not because of your code.

- Check that your files aren't also open in Excel at the same time.
- Check that your files aren't encrypted.
- Check that your version of xlrd supports the files you are reading

In the above order. Any of the above could have caused your error.